# Comparing Date Objects Showing Unexpected Results

Tags: javascript

I have some code here that:

- Let's you input waking time in the format "hh:mm"
- Outputs a list of sleep times that gives you 90-minute multiples of sleep periods (this list will suggest a sleep time of anytime after 8pm)

  ```
  var inputTime = prompt("input wake up time");
  var colonPosition = inputTime.indexOf(":")
  var inputHrs = parseInt(inputTime.substring(0, colonPosition));
  var inputMin = parseInt(inputTime.substr(colonPosition + 1, 2));

  var timeNow = new Date();
  timeNow.setHours(inputHrs);
  timeNow.setMinutes(inputMin);
  timeNow.setDate(timeNow.getDate() + 1)

  var sleepTime = new Date();
  sleepTime.setHours(20);

  while(timeNow > sleepTime) { 
    timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() - 90);
    document.write(timeNow + "<br />")
  }
  ```

If i input a wake time of 9:00, the output includes 19:30.

Why isn't my *while* conditional filtering out 19:30 in the output?

Comment: Does flipping the two lines in your `while` loop give you the desired result?
(i.e.) `while(timeNow > sleepTime){document.write(timeNow + "<br />"); timeNow.setminutes(timeNow.getminutes()-90);}`

Comment: What is the complete output of your script?

Comment: @Hans yes that worked, understand it now! Thanks

Comment: @artze No problem, and just for future reference I suggest posting a jsfiddle with your code when asking a question, it makes it much easier for people to help and some people on here will berate you if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't my while conditional filtering out 19:30 in the output?

You're using your while-loop like a for-loop, but your [*afterthought*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for-loops) is running just *before* your actual code. You're changing the value of your conditional to something falsey after you've checked it.

You should move subtracting 90-minutes to the end of the while block.

```
while(timeNow > sleepTime) { 
  document.write(timeNow + "<br />");
  timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() - 90);
}
```